# Use htaccess to append a query string to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I need to append query strings to certain URLs for campaign tracking/form submission. so for instance, i need http://domain.com/page/ to redirect to http://domain.com/page/?Campaign_ID=123456

The way i tried to set it up is giving me a redirect loop error message when i try to visit domain.com/page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
Redirect 301 /page http://domain.com/page/?Campaign_ID=1234656
```

I also tried it with RewriteRule instead, and that is also giving me the loop message:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^page$ http://domain.com/page/?Campaign_ID=1234656 [L,NE,R=301]
```

i'm sorry if this question has already been answered on here. i searched for awhile and couldn't find it, so please don't yell at me for posting. i did try to find it on my own. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^page/?$ http://domain.com/page/?Campaign_ID=1234656 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: this works for whichever page's RewriteRule i list first, but for any after that, i get the redirect loop message. i can keep doing the RewriteCond before each RewriteRule, but it would be ideal to be able to list multiple rules after the condition. i tried removing the L flags from the rules, but then the query string drops off entirely. This will work, but if you have an idea for getting this working with just the one instance of the condition and then multiple rules, i'm all ears. thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2930880 *"i can keep doing the RewriteCond before each RewriteRule, but it would be ideal to be able to list multiple rules after the condition."* That's simply not how mod_rewrite works. For every set of conditions, they only apply to the **immediately following rule**. If you want it to apply to every page, then change page to "everything": `^([^/]+)/?$ http://domain.com/$1/?Campaign_ID=1234656 [L,NE,R=301]`

Comment: ok, so then if i need different query strings appended to different pages' URLs, my only option is to do one condition and one rule for each page?

Comment: @user2930880 Yes, unless you have access to the server's config file and create a `RewriteMap`, then you can use the map in the htaccess file to map the ^([^/]+)/?$ part to a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/page/)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1?Campaign_ID=1234656 [L,R=301]
```