# Google Analytics showing 301 redirect as referral

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

I have universal analytics installed on my site. The .htaccess file does a location-based 301 redirect. Here is what happens:

www.mysite.com redirects to www.mysite.com/uk if the user is based in the UK. The same happens for .fr and .de.

In analytics I have added mysite.com to the referral exclusion list however analytics is still putting out mysite.com as the referrer for my traffic.

Here's my GA snippet:

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The create event part was set to 'auto' instead of specifically naming the domain as it is above, however that made no difference.

I've asked many people and many experts and none have the solution. Any help out there?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the 301 occurs before you've loaded the analytics-script, so maybe that referral exclusion list isn't a factor in this case (you should still leave it on there, though). Perhaps you could append a querystring when redirecting and filter your traffic based on that.

Comment: Ok thanks, any tips on how to do this querystring? That's probably a bit beyond my level of expertise

Comment: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151901/use-htaccess-to-append-a-query-string-to-url ?

Comment: The problem is that method will simply output a campaign name that I specify as the source. So people visiting the .eu/uk page will have the source as "mycampaign"? Currently Analytics says the source to .eu/uk is a referral from .eu. Am I just reading that other article incorrectly?