# .htaccess setup resulting in a self-referral in Google Analytics

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

My .htaccess set up is causing Google Analytics to display my own domain as a referral for the majority of my website traffic.
So, my website is called mydomain.com. When I track the source of traffic in Analytics, a large percentage of the source is "mydomain.com".

I have tried adding mydomain.com to the referral exclusion list. I have also tried adding index.html as the default page but that hasn't worked. I inherited an overly complicated .htaccess file which I have now simplified to the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^uk/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=302,NE,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

Can anyone spot any errors or something I'm missing here that's causing the self-referral? I have spent many hours researching and trying solutions but nothing is working

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984238/google-analytics-showing-301-redirect-as-referral

Comment: Unfortunately not, that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what is causing the self-referral in your .htaccess file. (I'm dealing with the same thing on one of my sites.)

1. Traffic comes to your site to a non-www address. (At this point the referral is wherever they came from.)
2. Before anything else, your site loads the .htaccess file and sees it needs to redirect to a www domain.
3. Traffic is then redirected to your www domain. (At this point the referral becomes your own site. As you said "mydomain".)

This answers the "what is causing the self-referral in your .htaccess file?" question. However, I am still trying out how to fix it for myself as well.